# Determine if List<Type> contains ICollection<dynamic>

Tags: c#, generics

I need to determine if a List contains ICollection where T is dynamic and not known at compiletime. Heres my code to better understand what I mean:

```
private void RefreshDataSource<T>(ICollection<T> dataSource) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
   dynamic row = view.GetFocusedRow(); 
   //Get's the focused row from a DevExpress-Grid
   //I don't know the type because it's MasterDetail and the view can be a DetailView. In this case type T isn't the underlying type.

   //Getting all Properties
   var dummy = dataSource.FirstOrDefault();
   var props = dummy.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToList();

   //Now comes the real problem, I need to determine the Detail Datasource
   //and to do this I want to check if there is a Property from ICollection<typeof(row)>

   //How can I check on ICollection<typeof(row)> instead of row
   //IsAssignableFrom would better fit my needs but I don't get how to solve my problem with it.
   var detailSource = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(row));
}
```

The code is broken to the important points, so don't wonder if sth. doesn't makes sense in your eyes ;-). Is there any way to check on `ICollection<T>` where T is a dynamic type and just know at runtime?

Notice that the given T on top of the method isn't the type of row, because of MasterDetail relationship!!!

**UDPATE**

I think I need to clarify what I need. Think of me as a Grid. I'm getting a DataSource which is a `ICollection<T>` and every row is represented by an object of T. Now I'm using MasterDetail relationships so that T just represents one MasterRow in the Grid. The Rows of a DetailView are represented by any `ICollection<AnyClass>` which is defined as a Property on T.

Now I need to determine this `ICollection<AnyClass>` Property from T without knowing what AnyClass is at compile time. Because I know the DetailView I can do this:

```
dynamic row = view.GetFocusedRow();
```

So row is of type AnyClass and known at **Runtime**. But how can I find this `ICollection<AnyClass>` Property in the PropertyCollection of T? This is my problem.

Comment: I love reflection and can help you if you are describing the exact problem. Do you want to know the type name of "T" in ICollection<T>?

Comment: @Karthik AMR No, the last line of my code is the important one. There I want to check if props contains a entry where p=>p.PropertyType is of type ICollection<typeof(row)>

Comment: do you really mean `dynamic` or T`?

Comment: I really mean dynamic. Because T is the type of the DataSource, but if I'm on a DetailView the underlying type will be a ICollection<sth.> Property from T.

Comment: @Sebi Explain what you want to do, not how you tried to do it. `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` which means it can be treated as an `ICollection<dynamic>`. Do you mean that the List can contain other collections? That some of them may be `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`? You can use `.OfType<TWhatever>` to retrieve all items of a specific type from an IEnumerable

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you are trying to acchieve.

Comment: @Sebi it does, this has nothing to do with `dynamic`

Answer (score 1):

In general, this should do

```
.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(intf => intf == typeof(ICollection<dynamic>));
```

in case you meant `T`and not `dynamic`, simple replace them.

```
 .GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(intf => intf == typeof(ICollection<T>));
```

If you want T and subtypes of it, it gets more complicated

```
.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(intf => intf.IsGenericType && 
                                        intf.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>) && 
                                        intf.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssigneableFrom(typeof(T)));
```

**EDIT** Since you calrified what you actually need:

```
.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(intf => intf.IsGenericType && 
                                       intf.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));
```

It could be much simpler, but `ICollection<T>` does not implement `ICollection`.

Comment: So if props contains an Entry ICollection<MyClass> and row is MyClass at runtime this will be true? I would think that there must a Property ICollection<dynamic> than...

Comment: I'm not sure how well this will work - `dynamic` is a set of compiler tricks and the actual declared type of such objects is `object` - so I think the `typeof` will generate the same type that `typeof(ICollection<object>)` would - so some false positives are possible.

Comment: @CSharpie I tested this but it doesn't seem to work. Check for ICollection<dynamic> won't match a Property of type ICollection<MyClass> for example.

Comment: @Sebi Of course not. ICollection<dynamic> is not ICollection<MyClass>.

Comment: @CSharpie Yes but exactly this is what I need. I need to compare a ICollection where the generic part is known at runtime but not before.